# Is “simplicity is elementary” still hard? (Felgner’s 1990 theorem on simple groups, and subsequent work)

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, lo.logic, model-theory

I came across a reference in [this MathOverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/40217/2273) to an intriguing result of Ulrich Felgner [1]: among finite non-Abelian groups, the property of being simple is first-order definable.  According to that answer, he derives it as a consequence of the classification of finite simple groups (which seems very plausible, but tantalising).

**I would be interested to see a proof of this result** — either Felgner’s original paper [1], or (especially) if there have been any subsequent alternative proofs given, especially not relying on the CFSG.  Unfortunately I’ve been unable to access a copy of [1] — I can only find physical holdings at a few libraries in Germany (list on [WorldCat](https://www.worldcat.org/title/311478351)) — nor any other presentations of the result.  Hence my main question: **Can anyone recommend a physically/electronically accessible reference for Felgner’s result?**  I’d be happy with either Felgner’s original [1] or any subsequent work, and either electronic access or a more widely-distributed physical version.

References:

1. Ulrich Felgner, *Pseudo-endliche Gruppen.* (*Pseudofinite groups*), [MR1107758](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=MR&s1=1107758), Proceedings of the 8th Easter Conference on Model Theory (Wendisch-Rietz, 1990), 82–96,
   Seminarberichte, 110, Humboldt Univ., Berlin, 1990.

Comment: These 2019 slides by John Wilson, esp slide 9, provide more information and context: https://mat.polsl.pl/groups/binn/wilson.pdf